# TTY characters mixed up after device cat or Python print

Tags: command-line, tty

So, when I `cat /dev/input/mouse0` in a TTY, move the mouse around a bit, and then `ctrl-z` to stop `cat`, my terminal characters are all messed up.  Almost every single character gets swapped out for another character in the ASCII character set.  This same situation occurs when I execute this in Python 3.2:

```
print('\033[1;12mTest.\033[1;m')
```

The the same symptom does not appear on a shell in the GUI, only on the virtual terminals.  The problem does not go away if I log out.  I suspect that a certain escape code (which may be contained within the Python code) is remapping the ASCII byte codes to the character representations, but that is just a guess.  What is happening and how do I undo it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the command that I was looking for on [Command Line Fu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/).  The command is `reset`.  I tried it, and it worked perfectly, without logging out or restarting the system.

Answer (score 2):

When outputting binary files to the terminal, like your `cat /dev/input/mouse0`, you can send it ANY character. This can confuse the virtual terminal.

The character string **ESC [** introduces a "VT100 Control sequence" (compatibility with an old glass keypunch). Other characters like **^Q**, **^S**, **^N**, **^O** do magic things based on compatibility with Model 35 Teletypes with paper tape reader/punch.

When I'm trying to de-confuse a terminal, I do:

Is output frozen? Type **^Q** (ctrl-Q) (the XON character, to start the paper tape reader).

Type the command `stty sane`. If there are no characters echoed as you type, `stty echo` will restore the echo.

Read `man stty`, and you'll see how you can save a set of terminal settings, and restore them later!

BTW, stopping a program uses **crtl-C** to stop a program. **Ctrl-Z** just interrupts the program, in preparation for putting it in the background. Some programs catch **^C** and do some necessary cleanup, file saving, etc. on the way out. If you just **^Z** and run something else, this cleanup doesn't get done.

Comment: I have heard about using stty sane before, and have tried it.  Unfortunately, the results have been the same as always: it did not work, and a restart was required to allow me to use those TTYs again.