# Running sudo cat /dev/root has broken something

Tags: command-line, 22.04, storage

I initially ran the command `df -h` to see how much storage I had. I noticed the first result was `/dev/root`. I wasn't sure what this was, so I ran `sudo cat /dev/root` thinking this was a safe enough operation.

However, it appears to have affected something. My prompt for example, when in my home directory, looks like this `ü$` when it should look like this `~$`.

Whenever I try type `~` it shows up as `ü`.

Could someone please explain to me what's going on, and what exactly `dev/root` has to do with storage?

Comment: You've probably just sent some control characters to your terminal - see for example [TTY characters mixed up after device cat or Python print](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121855/tty-characters-mixed-up-after-device-cat-or-python-print)

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I just ran `reset` and it's back to normal.