# "cat ls" messes up my terminal's characters

Tags: command-line, bash, ls, special-characters, cat

when I go to my /bin directory and do `cat ls` it messes up my whole terminal's characters, even my input gets messed up and I have no option but to restart the terminal.
I was just watching a toturial and the guy was doing this, his terminal didnt get funky though.
I wonder why it happened, because I have used cat on other system files and it doesn't go off the leash.

[`cat ls`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkQIe.png)

[Now as you see at the bottom of my terminal everything is messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZXL1.png)

I have also used the `clear` command but it just clears the terminal and the input is still funky.

[After the `clear` command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRjDZ.png)

Comment: Related: [TTY characters mixed up after device cat or Python print](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121855/tty-characters-mixed-up-after-device-cat-or-python-print)

Comment: `clear`  is just like hitting control-L, it doesn't reset terminal alt-modes or fonts or whatever settings produce this effect.  For that, `reset` (which resets your terminal, not your computer; `shutdown -r now` is what would reset your computer.)  Or `tput reset` or `stty sane`.  Check the man pages of those commands if you want to know more about how they work and what settings they can reset to sane defaults.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What `cat ls` does if you are in your `/bin` directory is to display the contents of the file `ls` to the console. Alas, that is a binary executable. It contains characters that do not make sense to humans. Some of these actually may resemble escape sequences that allow to change settings in a terminal. Thus, this output can change setting in a random, unexpected and unpredictable way.

You can eventually restore things by entering "reset" (which on screen may look as `$ ⎼␊⎽␊├` ) at the prompt.

If you *really* want to look at the contents of a binary executable, consider `xxd ls` to see a hexadecimal representation, or `xxd -b ls` to see the file as it really is stored, as a series of 0 and 1. `objdump -d ls` displays, where possible, the assembler mnemonics represented by the code.

Comment: i am actually learning Linux, and in the tutorial nothing like this happened, so I was wondering why it happened I want to make more connection to Linux, so it's not actually "for fun".
thanks for your information though I understand now.

Comment: OK I see, I will remove the first sentence. I tried it in a full text console (tty), and that seems "resistant", i.e., does not become garbled.

Comment: A tutorial suggesting you type `cat ls` while your current working directory is `/bin` is a bad tutorial. Alas, there are many bad tutorials on the 'net.

Comment: i didnt ask if the toturial is good or bad.

Comment: @JohnDoe16 I suspect you misunderstood something in the tutorial, it's not likely that it told you to do this. Do you have a link to it?